# Create an object type based on a union of keys but with varying property types

Tags: typescript

I have the following Union of strings:

```
type Keys = 'a' | 'b' | 'c'
```

I want to create an object **type**, that its keys are from this union, and the values can be anything assigned in that **type**.

Normally, people do this on objects:

```
const myObj: { [K in Keys]: any } = { ... }
```

But I want to do it on a **type**.

Is there anything like the following?

```
type MyType: { [K in Keys]: any } = {
a: string,
b: number,
c: boolean,
d: any // Type error, you can only assign keys from the union Keys
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can create a type-level `Satisfies` utility type to try to somewhat emulate what [the `satisfies` operator](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/release-notes/typescript-4-9.html#the-satisfies-operator) does with expressions.  If all you cared about were assignability, then it would simply look like

```
type Satisfies<T extends U, U> = T;

type MyTypeGood =
    Satisfies<{ a: string, b: number }, { a: string }> // okay
type MyTypeBad =
    Satisfies<{ a: number, b: number }, { a: string }> // error!
    //        ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    // Type '{ a: number; b: number; }' does not satisfy the constraint '{ a: string; }'.
```

But apparently you also want to enforce [excess property checking](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/release-notes/typescript-1-6.html#stricter-object-literal-assignment-checks), which isn't really about type safety but more like a linter check.  If TypeScript had *exact types* as requested in [microsoft/TypeScript#12936](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/12936) then you could write `type MyType = Satisfies<{⋯}, Exact<Record<Keys, any>>>`, but it doesn't, so we have to modify `Satisfies` to check for and prohibit extra keys.  Possibly like this:

```
type Satisfies<
    T extends U & { [K in Exclude<keyof T, keyof U>]: never },
    U> = T;
```

That uses the [`Exclude` utility type](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/utility-types.html#excludeuniontype-excludedmembers) to get the list of excess keys (keys of `T` that are not present in `U`) and then [maps](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/mapped-types.html) these keys to a type which requires that their properties be the impossible [never type](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/narrowing.html#the-never-type).

Let's test it out:

```
type Keys = 'a' | 'b' | 'c'

type MyTypeGood = Satisfies<{
    a: string,
    b: number,
    c: boolean,
}, { [K in Keys]: any }>; // okay

type MyTypeBad = Satisfies<{ // error!
    a: string, // Types of property 'd' are incompatible.
    b: number,
    c: boolean,
    d: any
}, { [K in Keys]: any }>;
```

Looks good, more or less.  The error message might be a bit confusing, especially because it appears on the entire type and not just the `d` property, but we don't really have much control over where and how compilation errors appear in TypeScript. So that's about as close to what you're asking for as I can get.

[Playground link to code](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/LAKAdghgtgpgzgBwgYxgAgFIFc4BcCCccAlgOaQBGxANsbgJ5oDeoabaDC6AyhLsXABmxeAB4AKmhgAPXDDAATOGgCqAGlUA+NAF404gNyhW7TugCy9cfS4BxAPb2Fuk+3a9+QkXFFM0EAC40PAAnYjBSDQogsCwoChgQtABfDT9A4NwwiJTtAHo8tHsAawh6Vw4bCysqgCEIZx0Ktw8BYTF0mLiEkKiu+MSUtP8g0PDSXLQCqRCQ+xCAQgrpt1W2AD9Nre2d3a3lwusuNAByTrRYgZCDNGiL7sSb5JO0BXt4C-tcYL42xlwABboZD2MChCDhb5nEaZbKkJ4nAB0xhAyRRkFgiBQ6AAotJUEQANIwegABTmAOIVH4oOYFTMaFaXjEzXYkhkckUyhUaAAZMw0ABtQlocJoPHIahYBQwUTFEn2QT6DTy+iKrQAXRiMAAboNUqy2CptHpDCi3AzifRlHoThAXgAfU4UR2nZAnc2mKpoSxHGAOJy6Rm-Zk+FggNZsDJjCJqQ23fo9OMRyPIIIURzUGAQMDJtypAXC0VgNBWuBa-xgRjJTQ3aYlMqetgM311BpBpntMNTQqJOaLePRrLjDTTP3KdUIOZcEIMU4KF4QELocIgqBIfgULPIlNrO6XJPxtO3TPZ3PxhRBHPlXdDQsisVlivX3JGECgZJAA)